Debian: apt pin not working for kernel package
I have following pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/linux-image.pref:
Package: linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
Pin: release a=oldoldstable
Pin-Priority: 800

apt-cache policy shows pins as expected:
$ apt-cache policy | grep "Pinned" -A 2
Pinned packages:
     linux-image-amd64 -> 4.19+105+deb10u16 with priority 800
     linux-headers-amd64 -> 4.19+105+deb10u16 with priority 800

However apt list --upgradable would like to upgrade to buster-backports with priority 200. Which is not desired in this case:
linux-image-amd64/buster-backports 5.10.127-2~bpo10+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.19+105+deb10u22]


oldoldstable has priority 600
buster-backports has priority 200

 600 https://archive.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.debian.org
 200 http://archive.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=buster-backports,n=buster-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.debian.org

It's quite strange that the command apt upgrade would upgrade pinned packages. While apt-get upgrade would kept back the kernel packages.
$ apt policy linux-image-amd64
linux-image-amd64:
  Installed: 4.19+105+deb10u22
  Candidate: 5.10.127-2~bpo10+1
  Version table:
     5.10.127-2~bpo10+1 200
        200 http://archive.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.19+105+deb10u22 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.19+105+deb10u16 800
        600 https://archive.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages


Isn't the default pin priority for new versions 900 (or 1000, don't remember exactly)? Shouldn't you use a value higher than that instead of 800? NVM - I see you have noted backports is supposed to be 200.

I've updated the question. Priority 800 is the highest number I have in the config. I guess changing the number won't change ordering.

Are you sure that apt upgrade and apt-get upgrade behave differently on your system?

The problem here is that the installed version of the package (4.19+105+deb10u22) isn’t available from any configured repository. Given your pin-priorities, the version available in backports wins, because a priority between 100 (included) and 500 (excluded)

causes a version to be installed unless there is a version available belonging to some other distribution or the installed version is more recent

(see man apt_preferences). Thus version 5.10.127-2~bpo10+1 is a candidate because the installed version is older and isn’t available from some other distribution. Version 4.19+105+deb10u16 is ignored because it is older than the installed version and its pin-priority doesn’t allow downgrades.
To fix this, you can either

figure out what repository your installed version came from (debian-security, apparently), and restore that configuration:
deb http://security.debian.org buster/updates main


manually downgrade the installed version to the version available in the repositories
configure the kernel packages from backports to have a pin-priority strictly between 0 and 100, so that their backports are no longer considered for upgrades

As mentioned in JdeHaan’s answer, you could also put a hold on the package — as you correctly point out, that will force the installed version to be kept, which is less flexible than what you could do with pin-priorities; however since the 4.19 kernel used in Debian 10 is no longer getting updates (even in ELTS), that won’t make a difference here as long as you want to avoid backported kernels. (This lack of updates also means that from a security perspective, you might want to re-evaluate your options.)

The setup isn't ideal, that's for sure. The original buster-security repo for Debian 10 has been suspended however it's not available in archive yet: https://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian-security/dists/ It complicates the situation but doesn't explain why the upgrade process is considering upgrade to 5.10 package.

Maybe you can use 'apt-mark' to 'hold' a package instead of 'pinning' it.
See
apt-mark showhold

and
sudo apt-mark hold packagename


Yes, you're right. apt-mark hold linux-headers-amd64 should be enough. But apt-mark is limited to exact version, while pin should have wider possibilities, like sticking to given release, origin, etc.
